# How can i share image with text from android app to facebook? I am using Intent.ACTION_SEND to upload status or photo to facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share image with Caption on it from my android app.
How can i do it?

I am using Intent.ACTION_SEND to upload status or photo to facebook

Comment: Edit your question and make it more clear that you want to "share" it to Facebook if that is the case.

Comment: Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

See code from [this](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-update-facebook-status-via.html) link for complete integration of facebook into android application with complete source code and write below method instead of `postToWall(String message)`

```
public void postPhotoToWall() {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    final byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", "Message");
    parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);
    parameters.putString("caption", "test");

    try {
        facebook.request("me/photos");
        String response = facebook.request("me/photos", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        } else {
            showToast("Photo posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using facebook sdk?

Comment: I do not use it. i want to share picture from "App" to facebook by this code public void shareimage() {
  
 Bitmap  bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.u);
 String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bi,"title",null);
 Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
 
 Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 share.setType("image/png/jpeg");
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///res/drawable/u.png"));

 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image2222"));
 }

Comment: Please mention this "I am using Intent.ACTION_SEND to upload status or photo to facebook" in your question.

Comment: The above code is work with android facebook sdk, Tomorrow I will give you proper solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void share(View v) {
  //facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new PostDialogListener());

   Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
   parameters.putString("message", category_item_name_desc.getText().toString());
   parameters.putString("picture", categoryItemsModel.getImageUrl());
   parameters.putString("caption", txtDescription_desc.getText().toString());
   facebook.request("/me/feed", parameters, "POST");

   try {
      facebook.request("/me/feed", parameters, "POST");
      System.out.println("**********************POST**********************************");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```